# I can't download Minecraft Java despite many attempts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

I used to play both Bedrock and Java, and modded Java Minecraft on my Imac, I had this Microsoft account to buy Minecraft in the first place. Now that I switched to a Windows 10 laptop, and logged into the Microsoft account from there, there were so many problems that arose.
Mainly the Bedrock version could be downloaded (after so many attempts and downloading it from the XBox app in the Microsoft store), but Minecraft Java can't be downloaded from both the Microsoft store AND the Minecraft launcher. I downloaded Java in hopes that it would help but nothing changed. I also deleted and redownloaded .minecraft over and over again in the roaming files but nothing changed, I deleted and redownloaded the launcher as well and nothing changed. This is the message whenever I try to open Minecraft Java.

> Failed to download file.
> Name: oshi-core-6.2.2.jar
> URL: https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/github/oshi/oshi-core/6.2.2/oshi-core-6.2.2.jar
> Error details: schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
> Filename on disk: oshi-core-6.2.2.jar
> Path: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\libraries\com\github\oshi\oshi-core\6.2.2\oshi-core-6.2.2.jar
> Exists: Nonexistent

Comment: How old is the laptop you're using? I had a similar issue on my very old hand-me-down pc, where I could not download the (new) minecraft launcher at all (the pc would freeze upon attempting to download it) and the old launcher refused to open (haven't touched it in forever so I forgot the error message it came up with, something about being unable to update). tl;dr just how old is your laptop